# when using getRetryAnalyzerClass in TestNG, retry method not executing which is implemented from IRetryAnalyzer

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Requesting to help me on the below,

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 
Java Version: 1.8.0_141 
Maven Dependencies:- 
 * Selenium: 3.141.59 
 * TestNG: 7.0.0 
 
Issue 1: "retry" method which is being implemented from "IRetryAnalyzer" is not get executed when the test fails when i use "getRetryAnalyzerClass" which is implemented from "IAnnotationTransformer". 
But if i use "getRetryAnalyzer" retry method gets executed.

---

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation itestannotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    Class<? extends IRetryAnalyzer> retry = itestannotation.getRetryAnalyzerClass();
    if (retry == null) { 
        itestannotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryFailedTC.class); 
    }
```

---

When I debug, i see `IRetryAnalyzer retry = itestannotation.getRetryAnalyzer();` on the first run comes as `null` hence goes into the if condition. 
But in `Class<? extends IRetryAnalyzer> retry = itestannotation.getRetryAnalyzerClass();` on the first run comes as `class org.testng.internal.annotations.DisabledRetryAnalyzer` so it's not going inside the condition.

Issue 2: When i use `IRetryAnalyzer retry = itestannotation.getRetryAnalyzer()`, after the execution i get the below error.

```
===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0, Retries: 1
===============================================
[TestNG] Reporter [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0] failed <br>
at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(Unknown Source) <br>
at java.util.HashMap.putAll(Unknown Source) <br>
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.setParameters(XmlClass.java:231) <br>
at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.createXmlClasses(FailedReporter.java:199) <br>
at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.createXmlTest(FailedReporter.java:150) <br>
at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateXmlTest(FailedReporter.java:124) <br>
at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateFailureSuite(FailedReporter.java:64) <br>
at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateReport(FailedReporter.java:49) <br>
at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1062) <br>
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1005) <br>
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115) <br>
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251) <br>
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) <br>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and steps.

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation itestannotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        itestannotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryFailedTC.class); 
    }
}
```

2. In RetryFailedTC class write the code for  unimplemented methods for IRetryanalyzer interface.
3. In the test method use annotation`@test(retryanalyzer = Retry FailedTC.class )` for the test method.

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Class<? extends IRetryAnalyzer> retry = itestannotation.getRetryAnalyzerClass();
```

is giving expected output.

Whenever `retryanalyzer`  with `Retry class` is mentioned in `@Test` annotation then `retry` will have class name mentioned in `@Test` annotation else it will have `org.testng.internal.annotations.DisabledRetryAnalyzer`.

For now if u just remove the retry line and if condition it will work fine